# MVC Core return pdf from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, pdf-generation

I'm struggling with concept.
Expected result is to return a dynamically generated pdf file to the user. I'll most likely generate the pdf with a library that converts html to pdf, such as IronPDF etc., as that seems to be the reasonable way at the moment.
Until now, I've created the pdf in an API controller that returns the pdf file to the user. So far I've used PDFSharp and MigraDoc. However, if I understand correctly, it would be a lot easier to use the controller to convert a html file to pdf and return that.

The question at the moment is:
**Should I generate the html file in another controller, and then call that result from the controller that returns the pdf?**
It seems a little cumbersome to create a html string in the controller and then return that as converted to pdf.

So in my mind I would have a controller that returns a normal view, and in my ConvertToPdfController I would call the resulting page of the first controller. Am I anywhere near a reasonable solution?

The solution would be something like this:
A web page would have a "Print invoice" -button. This button would call my `PrintPDFInvoice` method in a controller. This `PrintPDFInvoice` method would return the result of my `GenerateInvoice` method in the same controller, which does all the work of generating the invoice as a html page and returning a normal view, therefore a complete html page. And my `PrintPDFInvoice` method calling that page would just convert that page to pdf.

I know this is unclear, but so it is to me. I need to have a controller returning a normal view to generate the html page. Then another controller would convert this to pdf. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: I don't understand, you want to return a pdf file to the client and your asking if you should return it as FileResult or HTML?

Comment: I know it's confusing. I edited the question. Don't really know how to clarify it more. I don't have a clear idea on the approach yet.. :/

Comment: So you're wondering 1. if you should generate the invoice in HTML then convert the HMTL to PDF,  or 2. Generate the PDF with data? Am I correct? Then return the result to the user? I've done both and I have taken option 2. I created a template PDF file then replaced the data I needed by modifying the xml with the new values. It made modifications very easy.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. The reason I'm wondering is that the older libraries, like PDFSharp and MigraDoc allow me to generate the pdf in the controller with relatively good control and ease. The more recent libraries all seem to aim to convert html to pdf and it's a pain to generate the html in the controller and convert and return that. Any good (and reasonable price) libraries to generate pdf from code?

Comment: I use https://www.evopdf.com/ It's unlimited for $1400, because we automate a lot for multiple clients. You can choose to dabble with option 1 html to pdf or option 2 template with data approach.

Comment: Have you tried using rotativa?

Comment: Have you considered to [create the pdf from the client-side](https://medium.com/@weihui.guo/save-html-page-and-online-images-as-a-pdf-attachment-with-one-click-from-client-side-21d65656e764)? You can use JsPDF or alike to create a pdf with a "Print invoice" button.